# Need Handlebars helper to check if value is > 1 or < 2 then render code depending upon which condition is met

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have setup a login route which saves user data that includes a value under the key `permission_id`. This `permission_id` must be checked to see if it is > 1 or < 2. If it is < 2, I want to render the first piece of HTML, else, render the second. This permission value is being used to determine if the user can see certain content or not.

I currently have a helper written as follows in my server file:

```
const hbs = exphbs.create({
    // create custom helper 
    helpers: {
      permissionCheck: function(value){
        if (value < 2) {
          value = true;
        } else {
          value = false;
        }
      }
    }
});
```

In my handlebars file, i am attempting to write the following:

```
{#permissionCheck req.session.permission_id }}
{{else}}
{{/permissionCheck}}
```

Any suggestions?

I have tried to change the syntax to include my helper inside of () as {{#if (permissionCheck req.session.permission_id)}} but to no avail.

I am not sure how to write a helper to behave as a conditional statement in this manner but I need to be able to check this variable to render content appropriately.

Comment: maybe all you're missing is to `return value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as @Matthias stated in the comments, you must *return* a value from your helper. For example:

```
function (value) {
  return value < 2;
}
```

Second, your helper is *not* checking that `value` is greater than one, even though you said in your post that this is a requirement. Therefore, the helper should become:

```
function (value) {
  return 1 < value && value < 2;
}
```

Third, you are not understanding the difference between Handlebars' [Block](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html) and [Inline](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#helpers) helpers. When you invoke your helper with `{{#permissionCheck req.session.permission_id }}`, you are invoking it as a *Block* helper. However, since your helper returns a simple Boolean value, it is an *Inline* helper.

Therefore, we need to invoke it as an Inline helper from our template and we can use its returned value as the argument to an `if` (Block) helper which will determine what gets rendered. Example:

```html
{{#if (permissionCheck req.session.permission_id)}}
  <p>Secret stuff!</p>
{{else}}
  <p>Permission is required</p>
{{/if}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/5huk4yp3/) for reference.

Comment: @James P. I would like to know if this was helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was immensely helpful, particularly as a general explainer for how handlebars helpers function, i was entirely unaware of the inline / block type. 

Much appreciated.